# Typescript errors on creating instance via @nestjs/sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I am using Nest.js, ts and sequelize (@nestjs/sequelize, sequelize, sequelize-typescript) in my project.

I have such **User** model:

```
  Column,
  Model,
  Table,
  PrimaryKey,
  DataType,
  HasOne,
  AllowNull,
  Unique,
  AutoIncrement,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { UserLocationModel } from './user-location.model';
import { UserHealthIndicatorModel } from './user-health-indicator.model';
import crypto from 'crypto';

@Table({ tableName: 'User' })
export class UserModel extends Model<UserModel> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Unique
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  id: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.STRING(256))
  name: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.DATEONLY)
  birthDate: Date;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Unique
  @Column(DataType.STRING(256))
  email: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.STRING(256))
  passwordHash: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.STRING(256))
  token: string;

  @HasOne(() => UserLocationModel)
  location: UserLocationModel;

  @HasOne(() => UserHealthIndicatorModel)
  status: UserHealthIndicatorModel;

  static makePasswordHash(password: string): string {
    return crypto
      .createHash('sha512')
      .update(password, 'utf-8')
      .digest('hex')
      .substring(0, 526);
  }

  static makeRandomToken(): string {
    return crypto.randomBytes(256).toString('hex').substring(0, 256);
  }
}
```

And following register method:

```
public async register(
    email: string,
    password: string,
    name: string,
    birthDate: string,
  ): Promise<string> {
    const oldUser = await this.userModel.findOne({ where: { email } });
    if (oldUser) {
      throw new ConflictException('User already exists');
    }
    const passwordHash = UserModel.makePasswordHash(password);

    const user = await this.userModel.create({
      email,
      passwordHash,
      name,
      birthDate: new Date(birthDate),
      token: UserModel.makeRandomToken(),
    });

    return user.token;
  }
```

Typescript unable to compile:
**error TS2345: Argument of type '{ email: string; passwordHash: string; name: string; birthDate: Date; token: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserModel'.**

I can remove generic from model (change "**class UserModel extends Model<UserModel>**" to "**class UserModel extends Model**") or comment ts compiler, but i wonder if exist more exquisite solution of this problem.